# Triple Integral Setting up bounds for region over a cone and sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I am calculating the triple integral:

$$    
\iiint\limits_{D} (z^2 + z)\ dV
 $$

Where D is $x^2+y^2+z^2≤4$ and $z^2≤x^2+y^2$

I understand that the first part D is the space inside or on the sphere with radius 2. For the second part of D which is a cone I am confused by how the inequality works in that sense which  or side of the cone that is also satisfies the first part of D that region represents. Which is what I would like to get explained.

Comment: Do you have a good visual representation of D? If not, I would recommend geogebra's 3D calculator to plot D.

Answer (score 1):

$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ makes a double cone.

Here is a picture

[image]

Now $z^2 \le x^2 + y^2$ Would say that we are including values of $z$ such that $|z|$ is less than the radius of the cone.

Is that "inside the cone" or "outside the cone"?

Comment: ok so the cone equation is starting to make sense $ x^2 +y^2$ in the cone equation represents the radius^2 of the cone which depends on the value of $z$ as by the radius we mean the radius of the circle at the "top" of the cone. or the biggest radius throughout the whole cone so to speak but the radius is allowed to be bigger than the radius of the cone is at $z$ if it was an equality so that means outside the cone. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{r=0}^2  \int\limits_{\phi = -\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\ \int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{2 \pi}\ r \left( (r \cos \phi)^2 + (r \cos \phi) \right) dr\ d \phi\ d \theta = 2 \pi  \left(2+2 \sqrt{2}+\pi \right)$$